# How to allow user to SSH-connect to VM deployed on host without access to host itself

Tags: networking, ssh, qemu, tunnel

I have an UbuntuOS host (let say, `150.15.15.15`) and another UbuntuOS virtual machine (`192.168.7.2`) deployed on that host. I want to configure SSH-tunnel on host so that remote user can connect to VM without need to connect to host first.
So instead of

```
USER ---ssh user@150.15.15.15---> HOST ---ssh root@192.168.7.2---> VM
```

do something like

```
USER ----ssh root@150.15.15.15 -p ???----> VM
```

I tried to append

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on host and execute on host

```
ssh -4 -R 2222:192.168.7.2:22 127.0.0.1
```

so that traffic received by host on port 2222 will be transferred to VM. When I do

```
netstat -tulpn
```

I see that port `2222` is in `LISTEN` state

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2222          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

And now (as I supposed) there should be a tunnel that allow remote user connect to VM with command

```
ssh root@150.15.15.15 -p 2222
```

but got

```
ssh: connect to host 150.15.15.15 port 2222: Connection refused
```

Where did I take a wrong turn?

Answer (score 1):

Your `netstat` output shows that port 2222 is listening on loopback interface only.
Did you restart the ssh server on your host after editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, to pick up the configuration change?

I tried a scenario similar to yours, only I restarted sshd after changing the config file, and my `netstat` output shows

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

`0.0.0.0:2222` indicates that port 2222 is now listening on all interfaces. And the connection from outside to port 2222 works now and connects to the target machine as expected.

Comment: So I need to do something like `sudo systemctl restart ssh/sshd`, right? It seem that I have no rights to manage some services, so need to ask admins. This might take a while. I will provide feedback right after ssh restarted...

Comment: Instead of using ssh with `-R` parameter to create a tunnel, you can use a program that is specifically designed just for port forwarding, like `tcppm` from the 3proxy package: https://3proxy.ru/ . You can run just: `tcppm -d 2222 192.168.7.2 22` to have port 22 on machine 192.168.7.2 forwarded to port 2222 on host. `socat` can also be used for the same purpose, but I don't know the detailed syntax.

Comment: After host reboot it still displays as `127.0.0.1:2222` and not `0 0.0.0.0:2222` even if I do `ssh -4 -R 2222:192.168.7.2:22 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Worked with `socat`. Thanks for the tip

Comment: `0.0.0.0` at the end of `ssh` command is wrong, you aren't connecting to 0.0.0.0, you are connecting to localhost. Try with 127.0.0.1 as previously, or try the following: `ssh -4 -R 0.0.0.0:2222:192.168.7.2:22 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by executing on host

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:2222,fork TCP:192.168.7.2:22 &
```

and

```
ssh -p 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@150.15.15.15
```

on user side